# Install Debian with only essential packages

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I am attempting to build an *extremely minimal* installation of Debian.

What is the best way to install the operating system with ***only*** packages marked as *Essential*, excluding *Important* and *Recommended* packages?

Will Debian even run in this configuration?

---

**Note:** Following [these instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en) still seems to install some packages labeled *Important*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the smallest possible system, follow [the instructions you linked to](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en), but specify `--variant=minbase` on the `debootstrap` command line. This will install only `apt`, essential packages and their dependencies.

You will always end up with packages not flagged as "Essential": some of the dependencies of essential packages aren't themselves "Essential" (they effectively become essential transitively).