# List of Debian packages with essential priority

Tags: debian, debootstrap

From my understanding, the `debootstrap` program with the `minbase` option only installs packages with "essential priority" (and possibly `apt`). Is there a web resource which lists all packages with different priority levels? All I really need is a list for priority levels of essential, required, important, and standard and I do not need optional and extra.

Comment: Does it have to be web-based?

Comment: @StephenKitt yes, I don't want to have to install a debian chroot just to find out what packages will be installed.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73244/209677)? Priority and essential [are different fields](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#source-package-control-files-debian-control)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m not aware of anything giving the information you’re after, on the web. (Arguably it should be added to the package pages.) You can however get the information you’re after by querying the [UDD](https://wiki.debian.org/UltimateDebianDatabase), for example using the [unofficial, publicly-accessible UDD mirror](https://udd-mirror.debian.net/):

```
$ psql --host=udd-mirror.debian.net --user=udd-mirror udd --password
```

will connect to the server, then

```
udd=> select distinct package, version, section, priority from packages where essential = 'yes' and release = 'stretch';
```

will list all essential packages from Stretch (the `distinct` is useful because binary packages are listed per architecture), and

```
udd=> select distinct package, version, section, priority, essential from packages where priority in ('required', 'important', 'standard') and release = 'stretch' order by priority, essential, package;
```

will list all required, important, and standard packages, with the priority information.

There is also a detailed list of all the current contents of `minbase`, on the [Buster priority requalification page](https://wiki.debian.org/BusterPriorityRequalification).

Answer (score 0):

1. [Install Debian with only essential packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280716/install-debian-with-only-essential-packages)

   It says

   > To get the smallest possible system, ..., but specify --variant=minbase on the debootstrap command line. This will install only apt, essential packages and their dependencies.
   > You will always end up with packages not flagged as "Essential": some of the dependencies of essential packages aren't themselves "Essential" (they effectively become essential transitively).
2. If you look on the Debian various package pages, e.g. https://packages.debian.org/stretch/synaptic
   you will see there is a colored key which lists

   > depends, recommends, suggests,  enhances

Comment: I don't see anything about priority on the webpage. How do I know if `synaptic` is essential or important or something else?